# Formula for function

Tags: calculus

I am self-learning mathematics and I don't know the exact language of math. I am trying to learn calculus by using Gilbert Strang's book "Calculus". There is an interesting problem that I want to solve, but I can't find a solution. This problem is about how to represent functions using "$j$" letter.

For example I have this function which outputs: $0 1 0 1 0 1 \ldots$ and I want to represent that function as $f$ by using $j$, which is a number that tells which number I am looking at. So first $f \to 0$ would be $j \to 0$, second $f\to 1$ will be $j \to 1$, third $f \to 0$ will be $j \to 2$, fourth $f \to 1$ will be $j \to 3$ etc.

I have found that if $j$ is odd, then $f$ is $1$ and if $j$ is even, then $f=0$. So I came up with this two functions $f_{j} = j^0$ and $f_{2j} = j-j$ (it is really hard to represent my notebook writing in web text, those $j$ and $2j$ in round brackets represent that they are written under f).

So how can I represent this two functions as one function?
Something like:

$$ f = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if $j$ is an even number} \\  1 & \text{ if $j$ is an odd number} \end{cases}$$

I hope I explained the problem pretty well, so you have understood it.

Comment: In addition to Michael’s good suggestions, mathoverflow and MSE both support [latex](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Learn_LaTeX_in_30_minutes) for typesetting mathematical formulae; spend a little time learning the syntax and you’ll have those $j$’s and $2j$’s $f_{\text{under an $f$ where they belong!}}$

Comment: In your own words: "if $j$ is odd then $f(j)=1$ and if $j$ is even then $f(j)=0$." How about $$f(j)=j\mod 2$$ ?

Comment: Although @KurtG. provides a very nice and compact way to write $f$, there is nothing wrong with defining a function as "$f(j) = 0$ if $j$ is even and $f(j) = 1$ if $j$ is odd."  When first learning math, it is easy to get used to always having functions represented by formulas, but there is nothing wrong with having functions defined piecewise (or even less explicitly) as long as you're precise about what the function does.

Answer (score 1):

Your piecewise notation is close. I would use something like:
$$f(j) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $j$ is an even number} \\ 1 & \text{if $j$ is an odd number}\end{cases}$$
In physics it is common to describe the relationship between numbers using variables, as "when $t = 2$, $x = 3$" or your "when $j = 2$, $f=0$". In math, however, it is common to describe the relationship between numbers using functions: to define $x(t)$ as a function where $x(2) = 3$, or to define $f(j)$ as a function where $f(2) = 0$.

Here $f$ is a function, and $f(j)$ is the number we get when we plug $j$ into $f$, so we want to say "the number we get if we plug $j$ into $f$ is $0$ if $j$ is an even number and $1$ if $j$ is an odd number".
$$f(j) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $j$ is an even number} \\ 1 & \text{if $j$ is an odd number}\end{cases}$$
What you wrote,
$$f = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $j$ is an even number} \\ 1 & \text{if $j$ is an odd number}\end{cases}$$
Reads as "$f$ is $0$ if $j$ is an even number and $1$ if $j$ is an odd number", which is slightly different, implying that $f$ is a variable representing a number instead of a function. We can still understand what you mean, but this could cause problems if you wanted to write a computer program. A computer would be very unhappy if you wrote `sqrt(abs)` instead of `sqrt(abs(x))`.

A few other notes: $0^0$ is undefined, just like $\frac{0}{0}$.

Also, you can produce this function using powers of $-1$: $$f(j) = \frac{1-(-1)^j}{2}$$ although this doesn't communicate your intention like the piecewise function notation does.